# What controls whether PhoneGap opens the Android browser?

Tags: android, cordova

Sometimes PhoneGap opens web pages in the Android browser, sometimes it opens them in its UIWebView. The behavior varies from version to version of Android.  For example, in ICS window.open() opens links in the Android browser, but the 2.3 emulator opens such links in the WebView.

What controls whether the link is opened in the Android browser or in the WebView?

Comment: I have found that on ICS the DropGap.java subclass of `WebViewClient` fires a `android.intent.action.VIEW` intent for the URI if it's not whitelisted. Which launches the external browser.  (There are also a bunch of built in schemes that fire intents, like `mailto:`, `geo:`, `sms:`, which fire other appropriate events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've found so far:

Things that fire the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method will launch an external browser if:

- the URL is not white-listed
- some schemes (`sms:`, `tel:`, `geo:`, `mailto:`)

But, the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method is not always fired -- on Android 2.2 and previous (and maybe 2.3?) Javascript techniques to trigger a page load (such as `window.open()` or `document.location.href =`) do not fire the method, and therefore load in the WebView regardless.

Links physically clicked by the user seem to always fire the method. Using the JS event mechanism to fire a click event on a link may also work, I haven't tried it.